# What conditions are required on a function for the set to be convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Let f : R → R. For each of the following set X, find the condition on f
for X to be a convex set.
(a) X = {(x, y) : y = f(x)}.
(b) X = {(x, y) : y ≥ f(x)}.
(c) X = {(x, y) : y ≤ f(x)}.

Can the answer to (a) be the constant function?

Does (b) and (c) refer to the lower and upper contour sets?
We know that if the lower (upper) contour set is convex then the function is quasiconvex (quasiconcave), so is that the condition for f? For it to be quasiconvex(quasiconcave)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In (a), the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y=f(x)\}$ is the graph of $f$, so the set is convex if and only if $f$ is affine -- the constant function is a particular case;
- In (b), the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: y\geq f(x)\}$ is the epigraph of $f$ (the set of points on or above its graph), therefore the set is convex if and only if $f$ is a convex function;
- In (c), the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\leq f(x)\}$ is the hypograph of $f$ (the set of points on or below its graph), hence the set is convex if and only if $f$ is a concave function.

Comment: It is best not to answer homework style questions without from first time uses without proper context and effort. Typically I ask "What have you tried so far?" in the comment. After they show their effort I can help address any issues of understanding. That way I ensure they're learning.

Comment: Best for whom??